# Set builder notation meaning when it includes vertical bars and colons?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am doing this problem, but I simply have no idea how to tackle it because I don't really understand what its saying. I know | and : mean such that but have never seen them together. If someone could explain what these two sets mean in words that would be amazing!

$$\{x\in \mathbb{Z}: 7|x\} = \{x\in \mathbb{Z}: 7|(8x-14)\}$$

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

The colons here have their usual meaning in set-builder notation. The vertical bars, on the other hand, stand for the divisibility relation. For example, on the left-hand side, $7\mid x$ means that $7$ divides $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\{x\in \mathbb{Z}: 7|x\} = \{x\in \mathbb{Z}: 7|(8x-14)\}$$

The set of all integers, $x$ such that $7$ divides $x$

equals

The set of all integers, $x$, such that $7$ divides $8x-14$.